# Reference Cursor from another class

Tags: java, android

I have two class: `CursorAdapter.java` and `MainActivity.java`. In MainActivity I have `OnItemClickListener`.
How get refenerence Cursor in MainActivity to CursorAdapter class?

## CursorAdapter.java

```
    public class ListAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    public ListAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, int flags) {
        super(context, cursor, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.items, parent, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, final Cursor cursor) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to.
Here is solution:

Inside CursorAdapter:

```
public class ListAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    static Cursor cursor;
public ListAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, int flags) {
    super(context, cursor, 0);
    setCursor(cursor);
    getCursor();
}
public void setCursor(Cursor cursor)
{
    this.cursor = cursor;
}
public Cursor getCursor(){
    return cursor;
}
```

MainActivity:

```
public Cursor cursorAdapter;
public ListAdapter adapterDB = new ListAdapter(this,cursorAdapter,0);
```

to get reference Cursor inside MainActivity:
`adapterDB.getCursor()`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done much with the list adapters but this should work.

On the main class/activity location add this.

```
public static Cursor cursor;
```

On the location of the list adapter add this.

```
Main.cursor = cursor;
```

Comment: Error: `Unknown class Main.cursor`